# Selective batch restore in Titanium Backup?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup

Lately I upgrade my ROM (cm 10.1) quite often so I want to have my favourite applications ready after each upgrade. I got Titanium Backup Pro with root access.

I would like to know how to

1. install Titaninum Backup + the key after each ROM upgrade with the necessity to be connected to the internet
2. restore only bunch of my favorite application. I do not want to do full restore although I do full backup
3. restore system (cm) settings

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this in two ways:

- have *Titanium* create an `update.zip` with the wanted data. This you could then simply flash, and you are done
- *Titanium* also supports a kind of "tags": Setup a filter matching all the stuff you want, and save the selection as a tag (or tag the wanted items manually). Then select by tag and backup. Make sure to have *Titanium* sync its settings to your SDCard. After the ROM upgrade, first re-install *TB* (which then syncs with its settings from the SDCard), select the items by tag, and restore.

Comment: As a sidenote, new versions of *Titanium Backup* can now read contents from a CWM/Nandroid Backup. So apps from then entire ROM backup can be easily restored by *TB*  to your new ROM

Comment: That's true -- but then you'll may have to do that manually each time (which is why I skipped it in my description). The combination of "after each ROM upgrade" and "only bunch of my favorite applications" suggested it should need as few "taps" as possible for the restore (here: select tag, action restore, done).